# Building with jdk 1.7, Unable to call web service using jboss 4.2.3.GA ( runtime environment java 1.7). Error: Cannot build JAXB context

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse-juno, jboss-4.2.x

1. In eclipse, I am building my project with **jdk 1.5**, I am using **jre 1.5** and it is working fine with jboss 4.2.3.GA (if i am using jboss runtime environment **java 1.5**)...**no issue**
2. In eclipse, I am building my project with **jdk 1.7**, I am using **jre 1.7** and it is **NOT** working fine with jboss 4.2.3.GA (if i am using jboss runtime environment **java 1.5**)..**.not working ....no issue
   .**
   .
3. But the **issue is** with .....
   In eclipse, I am building my project with **jdk 1.7**, I am using **jre 1.7** and it is **NOT** working with jboss 4.2.3.GA (if i am using jboss runtime environment **java 1.7**).

In 3rd case the **project doesn't show any error**.
But **as i am starting the jboss.....On console i find the Error**...***Cannot build JAXB context***

---

***Or, JDK 1.7 is not compatible with jboss 4.2.3.GA ?***

---

**I am pasting the console description here:**

```
Initializing Application: /usr/home/
12:56:20,770 INFO  [[/lb]] app: Application Library correctly initialized!
12:56:20,773 INFO  [STDOUT] 
Application 'Library ' initialized at Wed Dec 05 12:56:20 IST 2012
12:56:24,179 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/software/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/deploy/lb.war/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build JAXB context
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:953)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.buildWebServiceMetaData(JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.java:154)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.setupProviderOrWebService(JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.java:50)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilderJSE.buildMetaData(JAXWSMetaDataBuilderJSE.java:61)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.start(UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.java:65)
    at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.start(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.LazyAssemblyWSFRuntime.start(LazyAssemblyWSFRuntime.java:66)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.JAXWSDeployerHookPostJSE.deploy(JAXWSDeployerHookPostJSE.java:52)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Failed to create JAXBContext
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:114)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:949)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at private java.lang.Throwable[] st.erpsapccn.bs.ip.admin.service.jaxws.IPWSExceptionBean.suppressed
        at st.erpsapccn.bs.ip.admin.service.jaxws.IPWSExceptionBean

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:105)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:108)
    ... 83 more
12:56:24,287 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console, warUrl=.../deploy/jmx-console.war/
12:56:25,426 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@f5e4ea04 { url=file:/software/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/deploy/lb.war/ }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: Cannot build JAXB context
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/software/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/deploy/lb.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1354692375941
  lastModified: 1354610826000
  mbeans:
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=default,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=jsp,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=LBRefDataWS,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=AlternateLoginServlet,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=LBAdminWS,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=app,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)
    jboss.web:j2eeType=Servlet,name=LBWS,WebModule=//localhost/lb,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none (state not available)


12:56:25,549 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-dlhl0664.dlh.st.com%2F10.199.3.147-23920
12:56:25,608 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-dlhl0664.dlh.st.com%2F10.199.3.147-23921
12:56:25,623 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)] Started in 44s:551ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link should be helpful for you:

http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2013/03/jboss-422-ga-to-jdk-7-or-jdk-6-migration.html

"Two important clues from the stacktrace are made bold. After skimming through JBoss JIRA, I managed to find out that the problem was with JBossWS Native implementation: JIRA comment. There is the commit that solves the problem connected with the fact that getSuppressed() method was added to Throwable in JDK7. Everything was clear now, but our JBoss 4.2.2 GA works with JBossWS Native 3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA. Upgrading WS provider to the jbossws-native-3.1.2 was not an option because of the risk. I decided to solve the problem in a different way. I downloaded the source code of the JBossWS Native 3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA and I added the following line:
excludedGetters.add("getSuppressed");
to the org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.AbstractWrapperGenerator class (as it is seen in the presented commit). Next, I compiled that class in isolation and I injected it into jbossws-core.jar. JBoss 4.2.2 GA started on JDK7 without any errors."

https://source.jboss.org/changelog/JBossWS?cs=16285&_sscc=t

Comment: Posts that rely entirely on links for their content are generally [not considered sufficiently detailed to be answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/150283). Please provide some context and explanation here, so that your post can stand alone should the links become inaccessible. Currently, without the links, this answer would not have enough information to provide a solution to the question.